# How to allow different login ID to be logged into the application for once in the same local computer

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton

I've a window application which consists of splash screen, login window, and the main window. As what I've searched, most of the single instance application checking is at the application startup (App.xaml.cs):

```
public partial class App: Application 
{
  private static Mutex mutex = null;

  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) 
  {
    const string appName = "MyAppName";
    bool createdNew;

    mutex = new Mutex(true, appName, out createdNew);

    if (!createdNew)
    {
      //app is already running! Exiting the application  
      Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    base.OnStartup(e);
  }
}
```

For my case, I want to allow only one user with different login ID to be logged into the application for once in the same local computer. How can I implement the method above in Login.xaml.cs or MainWindow.xaml.cs, since the method above is done in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: Does your app have a _server component_ that can manage session state?

Comment: Hi @MickyDuncan, my app need to connect to external server. After the user logged in successful, the user login ID will be displayed at the main window's title bar, so my thought is use the title name to check for single instance, but I have no idea how to do so since what I've found is check during application start up

Comment: @YWah if you want to do that like in comment, then just iterate through process list checking for window title and don't allow user to log into the program(on login button?)if there is more than 0 processes with such window title.

Comment: Checking for titles won't work if user **Fozzie Bear** attempts to use it on computer **A** and **B** in the same domain

Comment: @MickyDuncan, is on the same computer same domain, not different computer same domain

Comment: OK, can you reword your question because _"same computer domain"_ threw me.  If it is just local computer then I don't know why you mentioned _domains_ in the first place.  Thanks buddy

Comment: Hi @ArturMalendowicz, thanks for your answer, it gives me idea on how to do it

Comment: You should be able to just move that code to another class. It could even be a static class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing process main title window:

```
public void SingleInstanceHandler()
{
    Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(Process proc in procList)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
      {
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle == windowTitle) 
        {
          //Show relevant message
          Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This can be placed not only in App.xaml.cs, but also in Login.xaml.cs or MainWindow.xaml.cs